# Dot matrix printer is not continuing with half letter paper size

Tags: pdf, printing, jasper-reports, dot-matrix

I'm using an epson lx 300+II dot matrix printer and I'm using half letter size paper (tractor feed) and I have set custom paper size to width 8.5" and height 5.5".

When I print one page it prints fine but if print more than one pages first page print fine and for the other pages half letter size is not continuing (3/4 empty lines at the top so the bottom text prints at the top of the next page).
I'm using adobe reader to print a pdf document exported from jasper report and the OS is windows 7.

Comment: Check whether both, the printer driver AND the Acrobat/Reader Print dialog have the correct paper size; also check the preview in the Print dialog.

Comment: Thank you for helping!
I solved my problem. Problem was with the page margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the page margins; I remove the page margins and now it can be print continuously on half letter size paper.